# How to bind use port 514 so graylog can use as input source

Tags: graylog

How can I bind 514 so it can be used by graylog.

There are examples like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5514
```

But what I want is to use 514 using root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [authbind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) to allow the Graylog Java process to bind to a privileged port (below 1024).

Depending on how you've installed Graylog, you can simply edit the start script configuration file (see [default file locations](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/configuration/file_location.html)) and add `authbind` as a command wrapper.

Also take a look at [the example](https://github.com/Graylog2/fpm-recipes/blob/2.0/recipes/graylog-server/files/environment#L10-L12).